# Centering <div> without using "margin: auto;"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to center a div horizontally in the page on Google Chrome.

I tried using margin: auto; but I've read that this function is not supported in Google Chrome. As a result my div stays aligned to the left side of the screen.

If I use, for example, margin-left: 100px; the div does move toward the center of the page, but I don't want to center it manually.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <p>John Doe</p>
        <p>email</p>
    </div>   
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

div 
{
    border-radius: 5px;    
}

#header 
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}

#header p 
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Care to cite the source of the chrome issue?

Comment: I'm using Kimodo Edit 8.0 and using Google Chrome to preview the code. So I wouldn't be able to source, if that's what you mean???

Comment: No that's not what he means. He's asking you to substantiate your claim that you've "read that this function is not supported in Google Chrome."

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?151555-Margin-AUTO-does-not-work-in-IE ...I've seen similar info in various threads, saying that margin:auto; worked for FF but not in IE or Chrome.

Comment: Wow that is from 2007.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`margin: auto` will not work on a fixed (or absolute) position div.  Instead you need to set `left: 50%` and the left margin to negative half of the element width.

```
#header 
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZAqJM/

UPDATE: as of now most browsers will support `transfrom: translate` so you can comfortably do:

```
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly, I was looking for an option that kept the position fixed as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old but I think is worth mentioning that the following works like magic:

```
#header {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

For future references.

Answer (score 2):

Centering a `<div>` using `margin: auto;` works cross browsers. You need to make sure the div that you're trying to center is contained in a **block-level** element.

```
<div class="headerContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <p>John Doe</p>
        <p>email</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To properly center, your `div#header` needs to be *block-level* and must have a `width` and is a child element of a *block-level* element. (Technically `<body>` is *block-level* but you might want to maintain your header's "containership")

Therefore, remove the `position: fixed` from `#header { ... }`. Please see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/2sXdC/

Comment: Perfect, that works! Thank you so much! Question: How come I can't I include position: fixed;? What I had in mind was to keep the div#header fixed so that when I scroll down the page the div#header stays visible.

Comment: @user2209563 `position: fixed` and `position:absolute` will remove the element from the natural flow of the page, then the parent container will not include that element in its calculation of *height/width*. In your case, the parent container thinks it doesn't have `<div class="header">` as a child anymore.

Answer (score 0):

margin:auto is for the object that has width and set the left-right margin equally.

Div is basically BLOCK with FULL-WIDTH (100%) so set margin:auto is doesn't get anything since the width is full to the parent.

To make it work, you can did that by 2 ways,

1. use text-align:center for div -> this will align text inside div center
2. include width property in div (i.e. width:200px) and it will work fine.